# Where do I go to allow restricted settings?

Tags: settings, apk, accessibility

In an app called App Cloner, I am trying to toggle ON "Install automatically." When I try to toggle, I get a message of being redirected to Android Accessibility, where I can enable or disable this service.

I go to **Android Accessibility**, but it is grayed out, set to OFF. I tap on it to see the message: Restricted setting. This setting can't be changed unless you **allow restricted settings** in More options for specific apps in Settings > Apps.

I go to Apps in settings and I can't find an option of "More" under settings or in the app itself.

I do have other apps under Accessibility turned ON, but those apps were from Playstore.

S22+ Version 13

Comment: This [Guide](https://cubeacr.app/helper.html) for a similar requirement may help//On Android 14,I didn't see all those options but somehow managed to install. I don't recollect how I managed

Comment: It's a breadcrumb menu button in the application window page, on the top right of the screen.  Not all apps have it though.  Otherwise, you may need to grant it via ADB

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any of these on my phone.  So, I suspect what you need is

- Goto Settings
- Press on Apps
- Press on three vertical dot menu
- Press on **Special Access**
- Try the options here, I think my phone has different names to yours.

Answer (score 1):

On AOSP-based ROMs (Android 14 / LineageOS 21 used) the restricted setting can be toggled for an app on:

- settings → apps → see all [a number] apps → [select an app] → [the three-dot "hamburger" menu — see the screenshot] → allow restricted settings

[image: screenshot]

Comment: At the time of writing the apps with restricted settings on my device were KDE Connect, Key Mapper and KISS Launcher (all from F-Droid). I allowed all.